# Copy range sheet1 paste in selected cell sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to simply copy ranges of text from sheet 1 to sheet 2.  I don't want specific data ranges for the paste as I simply want to reuse the data to rotate assigned tasks (sheet 1) to apply to days/workers (sheet 2).

I started with a "record macro" that did not work then using this forum and several other sources ended up with this:

```
Sub rotationA()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B5").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

the line --- Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2:B5").copy  indicates error.  I am very new to vb and have rewritten the line a number of ways with no success.  The answers to other's question don't show the code being used in a manner that looks the same to me and I need help understanding this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting a range to paste into only a sheet. Try changing your code to the below:

```
Sub rotationA()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B5").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

This will paste into cell B2 on Sheet2 - change the

```
Range("B2")
```

portion of the second line to the cell you wish to paste into.